# kivy python flashing text

Tags: python, label, kivy

I would like to display flashing text (every 1 sec.) in my kivy app. I have searched through google but can not find any examples / information about it.

is it possible to do flashing text (label) in kivy at all?

EDIT:

The way I have done it is that I call a Clock to call a specific function every second to update screen.

I have defined global variable cnt as well and within above mentioned function I use if statements:

```
if cnt == 1:
    screen.ids.mynumber.text = 'STAND CLEAR'
if cnt == -1:
    screen.ids.mynumber.text = ''
cnt = - cnt
```

In this way I change cnt value every second to -cnt and either display text or not. any better way to do it in kivy?

Answer (score 4):

I would do this with an animation. Basically like that, with widget holding your text:

```
anim  = Animation(alpha=0, duration=0.1) + Animation(alpha=0, duration=1)
anim += Animation(alpha=1, duration=0.1) + Animation(alpha=1, duration=1)
anim.repeat = True
anim.start(widget)
```

It will quickly set the widget to transparent, keep it that way for a second then quickly set it to opaque, keep it for a second, repeat.

Comment: I'll also note that using transparency like this is probably better than the OP method of setting the text to `''`, as regenerating the text texture is much less efficient than modifying the opacity.